# WCF Client Extensibility: IParemeterInspector.AfterCall and exception handling

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-extensions

For my WCF client, I'd like to be able to do some **pre** and **post** work for every operation of a given endpoint.

- The **pre** work would like to make use of the **operation name** and the **input arguments**.
- The **post** work would like to make use of (again) the **operation name** and the **original input arguments** as well as the **outputs**/**return value** *or* any **exception** that occurred.

Given this, the `IParameterInspector` (with its `BeforeCall` and `AfterCall`) gives me *almost* everything I need.  The problem is that

- in the case of an exception, `AfterCall` is not called (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/26/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx)).

To help with that problem, I can add an `IClientMessageInspector` since its `AfterReceiveReply` does get called in the face of an exception.  This gives me the ability to

- determine if an exception (fault) occurred or not.
- do **post** work in the face of an exception

**Question:**

- Is there a way with the `IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply` to get (or create the equivalent) **exception** that represents what will eventually be thrown to the callers.  And if so, is there a way to mark the exception as **handled** such that the callers will not get the exception?
- Or, is there some other extensibility mechanism or other approach I should be using to meet my goals?

Comment: Do you want to replace a `FaultExcewption` by your `Exception`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to mute all exceptions. It's possible and can be done via replacing a message in `IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply` and "deserializing" the new message in `IClientMessageFormatter.DeserializeReply`.

The code listed below returns default value as result value when an exception was thrown.

Message:

```
public sealed class FakeMessage : Message
{
    #region Fields

    private MessageProperties properties;
    private MessageHeaders headers;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public FakeMessage(MessageVersion version, string action)
    {
        this.headers = new MessageHeaders(version);
        this.headers.Action = action;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Message Members

    public override MessageHeaders Headers
    {
        get { return headers; }
    }

    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override MessageProperties Properties
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.properties == null)
            { properties = new MessageProperties(); }

            return properties;
        }
    }

    public override MessageVersion Version
    {
        get { return headers.MessageVersion; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Message formatter:

```
public sealed class FakeMessageFormatter : IClientMessageFormatter
{
    #region Fields

    private IClientMessageFormatter baseFormatter;
    private object defaultReturnValue;

    #endregion

    #region Construcotrs

    public FakeMessageFormatter(IClientMessageFormatter baseFormatter, Type returnType)
    {
        this.baseFormatter = baseFormatter;

        if (returnType.IsValueType && returnType != typeof(void))
        { this.defaultReturnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(returnType); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IClientMessageFormatter Members

    public object DeserializeReply(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        if (message is FakeMessage)
        { return defaultReturnValue; }

        return baseFormatter.DeserializeReply(message, parameters);
    }

    public Message SerializeRequest(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters)
    {
        return baseFormatter.SerializeRequest(messageVersion, parameters);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And finally message inspector:

```
public sealed class FakeMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    #region IClientMessageInspector Members

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (reply.IsFault)
        { reply = new FakeMessage(reply.Version, (string)correlationState); }
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        return request.Headers.Action + "Response";
    }

    #endregion
}
```